# react native scrollview not working for me

Tags: javascript, react-native

My code consists on these three views:
App.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import HomePage from './pages/homepage/HomePage';

export default function App() {
return (
  <View
    style={[styles.container]}>
    <HomePage/>
  </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
},
});
```

HomePage.js

```
import CatPreview from '../../components/CatPreview'

export default function HomePage() {
  const colors_arr = [
      {color:'#2196F3',category:'מסעדה'},
      {color:'#03A9F4',category:'מזנון'},
      {color:'#00BCD4',category:'מלון'},
      {color:'#009688',category:'סושי'},
      {color:'#4CAF50',category:'חלומי'},
      {color:'#8BC34A',category:'לורם'},
      {color:'#CDDC39',category:'איפסום'},
      {color:'#FFEB3B',category:'רוק'},
      {color:'#FFC107',category:'אנד'},
      {color:'#FF9800',category:'רול'},
      {color:'#FF5722',category:'שלום'}
  ];
  return (
     
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
              {colors_arr.map((category,key)=>(<CatPreview color={category.color} category={category.category} key={key}/>))}
          </ScrollView>
  
    );
  }
```

CatPreview.js

```
export default function CatPreview({color,category}) {
  
  return (
      <View style={[styles.containerr,{backgroundColor:color}]}>
        <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:"center"}}><Text>{category}</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex:2}}></View>
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerr: {
      // flex: 1,
     height:"25%"
      
      
  },
});
```

[image]

For some reason im unable to scroll (resolving in me only being able to see the first four views).
Iv tried adding the `contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}` to the scrollview tag which helped spreading the view across the screen but Im still unable to scroll :( .

thanks everyone.

btw go easy on me im still new to native lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `height` value of the `CatPreview.js` component to the value mentioned in the below snippet

```
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,Dimensions} from 'react-native'

const height = Dimensions.get('window').height //Screen height

export default function CatPreview({color,category}) {
  return (
      <View style={[styles.containerr,{backgroundColor:color}]}>
        <View style={{ flex:1, alignItems:"center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
          <Text>{category}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerr: {
    //  flex: 1,
     height: height * 0.35 , //35%    
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to use **TouchableOpacity** instead of View.

CatPreview.js

```js
export default function CatPreview({color,category}) {
  
  return (
      <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.containerr,{backgroundColor:color}]}>
        <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:"center"}}><Text>{category}</Text></View>
        <View style={{flex:2}}></View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```